# SQL Optimization: multiplication of two calculated field generated by window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, cumulative-sum

Given two time-series tables `tbl1(time, b_value)` and  `tbl2(time, u_value)`.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4qkFJZLkZ3BK2tgN4ycCsj/1

Suppose we want to find the last value of `u_value` in each day, the daily cumulative sum of  `b_value` on that day, as well as their multiplication, i.e. `daily_u_value * b_value_cum_sum`.

The following query calculates the desired output:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
  t1.time,
  t1.b_value,
  t2.u_value * t1.b_value AS bu_value,
  last_value(t2.u_value) 
  OVER 
  (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('DAY', t1.time) ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('DAY', t2.time) ) AS daily_u_value
FROM stackoverflow.tbl1 t1
LEFT JOIN stackoverflow.tbl2 t2
ON 
    t1.time = t2.time
)
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('DAY', c.time) AS time,
    AVG(c.daily_u_value) AS daily_u_value, 
    SUM( SUM(c.b_value)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('DAY', c.time) ) as b_value_cum_sum,
    AVG(c.daily_u_value) * SUM( SUM(c.b_value) ) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('DAY', c.time) ) as daily_u_value_mul_b_value
FROM cte c
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

I was wondering what I can do to optimize this query? Is there any alternative solution that generates the same result?

Comment: Looks good. Any reason why you're not satisfied with it?

Comment: @SalmanA The entire dataset is over 3 TB, so it is very importantl to query it faster.

Answer (score 1):

[**db filddle demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=78beaa6078cba432c331746fdb7bd671&hide=3)
from your query: **Execution Time: 250.666 ms** to my query **Execution Time: 205.103 ms**
seems there is some progress there. Mainly reduce the time of cast, since I saw your have many times cast from timestamptz to timestamp. I wonder why not just another date column.

---

I first execute my query then yours, which mean the compare condition is quite fair, since second time execute generally more faster than first time.

---

```
alter table tbl1 add column t1_date date;
alter table tbl2 add column t2_date date;
update tbl1 set t1_date = time::date;
update tbl2 set t2_date = time::date;

WITH cte AS (
SELECT
  t1.t1_date,
  t1.b_value,
  t2.u_value * t1.b_value AS bu_value,
  last_value(t2.u_value)
  OVER
  (PARTITION BY t1_date ORDER BY t2_date ) AS daily_u_value
FROM stackoverflow.tbl1 t1
LEFT JOIN stackoverflow.tbl2 t2
ON
    t1.time = t2.time
)
SELECT
    t1_date,
    AVG(c.daily_u_value) AS daily_u_value,
    SUM( SUM(c.b_value)) OVER (ORDER BY t1_date ) as b_value_cum_sum,
    AVG(c.daily_u_value) * SUM( SUM(c.b_value) ) OVER
        (ORDER BY t1_date ) as daily_u_value_mul_b_value
FROM cte c
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, your modification improves the time of execution. I think there is some alternative solution that simplifies the two sub-queries above into one single query. But I have no idea yet!